# Why turbo c wraparound signed integer overflow every time though signed integer overflow is undefined?

Tags: c++, c, int, turbo-c

I have made signed overflow many times but each times turbo c wraparound.
For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  int i = 100000; 
  printf("%d", i);
  getch();
}
```

The output is `-31072` which is the expected output if wraparound is done.
In binary `100000(dec)` is `11000011010100000` and last 16 bits are store which
is `1000011010100000`. In two complement representation `1000011010100000` is `-31072`.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yG1OZ69H_-o). It does a nice job of explaining undefined behavior more and specifically talks about undefined behavior and the way we sometimes use hyperbole to describe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example doesn't have contain any signed overflows, so there is no undefined behavior.

(Assuming INT_MAX is less than 100000.)

The assignment:

```
int i=100000;
```

performs an implicit conversion from a type long, which is the type of the integer constant 100000, to type int. This result of conversion is implementation-defined<sup>1</sup> (or an implementation-defined trap is signal).

---

<sup>1</sup>(Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers 3)
Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.